# Convert images with folder

Tags: c#

I have problem with converting folders with images.
I only got work that its converting images but its not taking folders.

I dont figure out what I must change to get folders with images.

Example:

If I choose folder where is alot folders and converting with folders to converted Folder (C:\test) and if folder already exists then not converting.

Comment: It's unclear what your problem is. Do you want to convert a complete folder tree recursively? What does the last paragraph mean?

Comment: Yes if choose one folder and there is more folders then its converting all folders

Comment: Why do you save original bitmap by the end of your process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
string[] originalImage = Directory.GetFiles(txtFilePath.Text);
```

to

```
string[] originalImage = Directory.GetFiles(txtFilePath.Text, "*.*",
  System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

It won't do the optimisation you mentioned of checking if the folders exist, but it's a simple fix

Comment: Your method taking from all folder images and converting to "C:\" but not converting with folders.

Comment: That's because you are always saving to c:\ - you need to take into account the entire path. Also, you will probably need a Directory.CreateDirectory call to ensure the directory exists before trying to save a file to it